# probability expressed as an exponent

Tags: probability

I have been trying to understand some complex probabilities expressed using `exponents`.  I am used to treating probabilities as `logits`.  I obtained a result I was not expecting with exponents and am hoping someone might offer an explanation for the following simple example.  I realize this must be a very remedial request.  The probabilities in question come from fisheries.

```
A <- 0.10
B <- 0.75

# Presumably this is the instantaneous probability of A.
# An example is the instantaneous probability of mortality of fish with constant fishing 
pA.exp <- exp(-A)
pA.exp
#[1] 0.9048374

# Presumably this is the instantaneous probability of A then B.
pAB.exp <- exp(-(A * B))
pAB.exp
#[1] 0.9277435

# I was not expecting this product to equal pA.exp above but it does
pA2.exp <- exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
pA2.exp
#[1] 0.9048374

# I was expecting this sum would equal pA.exp but it does not
pA3.exp <- exp(-(A * B)) + exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
pA3.exp
#[1] 1.903053
```

As mentioned above I am far more familiar with probabilities expressed as `logits` and provide an example of what I had been expecting with the above `exponents`.

```
# probability of A
pA.logit <- exp(A) / (1 + exp(A))
pA.logit
#[1] 0.5249792

# probability of B
pB.logit <- exp(B) / (1 + exp(B))
pB.logit
#[1] 0.6791787

# I understand the probability of A and B
pA.logit * pB.logit
#[1] 0.3565547

# I understand this sum equals pA.logit
pA.logit * pB.logit + pA.logit * (1 - pB.logit)
#[1] 0.5249792
```

I realize my request for an explanation of `pA2.exp` and `pA3.exp` is very remedial, but it would also be very helpful.

**EDIT**

My original question was why does this relationship hold:

```
exp(-A) == exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
#[1] TRUE
```

The following was originally intended as an answer.  However, it is more accurately a detailed demonstration that the relationship does hold rather than an explanation for why it holds.  So, I have moved my answer to here and deleted the answer itself.

```
A <- 0.10
B <- 0.75
n <- 100

# instantaneous probability of survival
pA.alive <- exp(-A)
pA.alive
#[1] 0.9048374

# instantaneous sequential survival probability of A then B
pA2.alive <- exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
pA2.alive
#[1] 0.9048374

# instantaneous probability of mortality
pA.dead <- 1 - exp(-A)
pA.dead
#[1] 0.09516258

# instantaneous sequential mortality probability of A then B
pA2.dead <- 1 - exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
pA2.dead
#[1] 0.09516258

nA.dead <- n * pA.dead
nA.dead
#[1] 9.516258

nA2.dead <- n * pA2.dead
nA2.dead
#[1] 9.516258

ndead.AB <- n * (1 - exp(-(A * B)))
ndead.AB
#[1] 7.225651

ndead.AnotB <- (n - ndead.AB) * (1 - exp(-(A * (1 - B))))
ndead.AnotB
#[1] 2.290607

ndead.AB + ndead.AnotB
#[1] 9.516258

round(ndead.AB + ndead.AnotB, 8) == round(nA.dead, 8)
#[1] TRUE

round(ndead.AB + ndead.AnotB, 8) == round(nA2.dead, 8)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does this expression hold?

```
A <- 0.10
B <- 0.75

exp(-A) == exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Because that expression is simply a re-expression of:

```
log(X*Y) == log(X) + log(Y)
```

Where: `X = exp(-(A * B))` and `Y = exp(-(A * (1 - B)))`

Take the log of both sides of this expression: `exp(-A) == exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))`:

```
round(log(exp(-A)),8) == round(-A,8)
[1] TRUE

round(log(exp(-(A * B)) * exp(-(A * (1 - B)))),8) == round(log(exp(-(A * B))) + log(exp(-(A * (1 - B)))),8)
#[1] TRUE
```

So, `log(exp(-A)) = log(exp(-(A * B))) + log(exp(-(A * (1 - B))))`

Which equals: `-A == -A * B + -(A * (1 - B))`

Or: `A == A * B + A * (1 - B)`